# Dotnet core Dependency Injection of Parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

Suppose that I have the class

```
public class Entity : IEntity {
    public Entity(IDependency dep, string url)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class Dependency : IDependency {
    //...
}
```

Now when I want to use dependency injection I can do something like:

```
IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDependency, Dependency>();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IEntity, Entity>(); // how to inject the url
```

The problem, as you can see, is that I don't know how to inject a value of url (e.g. "https://google.com/"). I know structure map provides that with naming the parameters and their values.

Is there a way to inject a string into the constructor of `Entity` while using DI for the dependencies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to provide an implementation factory function using the `AddScoped` overload to configure how to initialize the implementation.

```
IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDependency, Dependency>();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IEntity>(provider => 
    new Entity(provider.GetService<IDependency>(), "https://example.com/")
);
```

Note how the provider is used to resolve the other dependency.

So now when ever an `IEntity` implementation is requested, the implementation factory will be invoked and the implementation resolved also with any configured dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the `Entity` take another class dependency that contains a url property.

```
public Entity(IDependency dep, IConfig config){
   ...
}

public Config:IConfig{
   public string Url {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Good solution over all. And I can also use the configuration builder provider by the framework.

Comment: Good solution if you can update the code, if you need to use 3rd party code, then the answer from @nkosi fits better.